# How to test local changes to Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to fix a bug in a Chrome extension. I installed the extension from the web store. I found the error. I opened the installed files and made changes that may or may not fix the problem locally. I saved the changes. Now Chrome complains and says "This extension may have been corrupted."

I have no idea if the change will work. I do not want to go through the build process and upload the modified extension to the web store just to test a three line change.

How do I get Chrome to just use the modified extension? Or can I just ignore the "This extension may have been corrupted" error?

Comment: I now know that I cannot just ignore the error. It is refusing to load the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I was seeing the "This extension may have been corrupted" error because I made the changes in place, meaning directly in "${LOCALAPPDATA}\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions${extension_dir}". When I instead made the changes to my Perforce workspace directory and used the "Load Unpacked" feature to install the extension from there it worked.